# Wait for ThreadPool to finish and start SingleThread

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

I am currently trying to make a program check if a number is prime or not, by using a ThreadPool of 10 threads and a second run where I check only with one thread. The idea here is that I also check the difference in speed between using ThreadPool of 10 threads and 1 single thread.

My issue is that I am a bit stuck on how I would go about waiting for the PoolThread to finish before launching the single thread operation.

I tried to synchronized a function in my PrimeTask class, but I am still very new to threads, and not sure why I am not getting the desired behaviour. I would love some insight what I am missing and why.

```
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class PrimeChecker
{
    private static ExecutorService executor;
    private final static long number = 9223372036854775783L;
    private final static int numberOfThreads = 10;
    private static long startValues;
    private static long endValues;
    static long startTime;
    static long endTime;

    private PrimeChecker() { };

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        init();
        runThreads();
    }

    private static void init()
    {
        startValues = 3L;
        endValues = (long) Math.sqrt(number) / 10L;
    }

    private static void runThreads()
    {
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numberOfThreads);
        System.out.print("Chekcing if " + number + " is a prime number, multithreaded.\n");
        for (int x = 1; x < 10; x++)
        {
            executor.execute(new PrimeTask(number, startValues, endValues));
            startValues = ((endValues / 10) * x);
            endValues = ((endValues / 10) * (x + 1));
        }
        executor.shutdown();

        singlethreadedPrime();
    }

    private static void singlethreadedPrime()
    {
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
        System.out.println("Chekcing if " + number + " is a prime number, singlethreaded.");
        executor.execute(new PrimeTask(number, startValues, endValues));
        executor.shutdown();
    }

    static class PrimeTask implements Runnable
    {
        private long number;
        private long startValue;
        private long endValue;

        public PrimeTask(long Numb, long startVal, long endVal)
        {
            number = Numb;
            startValue = startVal;
            endValue = endVal;
        }


        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
            if (isPrime(number, startValue, endValue))
            {
                endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                System.out.printf("Time millisecond: %d\n", (endTime - startTime));
                System.out.println(number + " is Prime");
            }
            else
            {
                endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                System.out.printf("Time millisecond: %d\n" + (endTime - startTime));
                System.out.println(number + " not Prime");  
            }
        }

        public static synchronized boolean isPrime(long n, long sV, long eV)
        {
            if((n % 2) == 0)
            {
                return false; // not prime
            }
            else
            {
                for(long i = sV; i*i <= eV; i+=2) 
                {
                    if(n%i==0)
                        return false; // not prime
                }
                return true; // prime
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Both `Executors` are doing exactly the same amount of work - and I mean literally.  In order for your code to take advantage of multiple threads, you actually need multiple tasks to be performed (each task is executed by a single thread). So in you `runThreads` method, you need to break down your work load into (maybe 10) parts, each part calculating a specific range of the whole (ie `(endValues - startValues) / 10` will give you the overall range for each individual task)

Comment: To answer your question: as usual, all you need to do is to read the javadoc: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#awaitTermination-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-. It's the very first method listed in the class!

Answer (score 0):

You used "execute", but you seem to want to wait for results.
So you can use submit() which returns a future.
You can thus wait for the future.get() (which is blocking).

With only one future, it's trivial. For 10 futures, you would pile up futures in a list, then when all submitted, it's fairly simple to call .get() on each one. The first ones will take some time, but the later ones will be faster, or not even block in .get() if already completed. (of course you could poll for future.isDone() but that's wasteful)

The executor.shutdown() which you use should wait for all in-progress task to complete, but the problem could be that they are not all in-progress but merely queued.

Finally, you could use a CountDownLatch to wait for all completions. Pass the countdown latch to all tasks.